# javac and javaws works but not java

Tags: 12.10, java

`javac` and `javaws` work from the command line but `java` for running a .class won't work.

I have updated my PATH, set JAVA_HOME, and checked links.

When I type `java myclass` I get "java" found in default-jre and a few others. When I run `java -version` the same thing, "java" found in default-jre.

I'm trying to use Sun Java jdk1.7.0 and the command line. It appears that Ubuntu thinks that Java jdk1.7.0 isn't installed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install java? What's the output of `which javac`?

Comment: The output is a compiled class, the class will run under eclipse. The command line output for "which javac" is /usr/bin/javac.

Comment: I've only been using Ubuntu for about six months, I appreciate the nudge in the right direction and not the answer. I followed the "which javac" and found that there is not "java link" in the file. Now I'm going to find a way to fix that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you should do the following:

```
sudo ln -s </path/to/java/install/directory> /usr/bin/java
```